# Data not displaying in the chart second time when a link is clicked

Tags: reactjs, bubble-chart, chartjs-2.6.0

I am working with Chartjs2- React. When I click on a link "NursingObs" it loads a bubble chart with appropriate points.

The second time I click the same link "NursingObs" it loads only the latest data and the rest disappears.

```js
const NursingObsComponent = ({
  NursingObservations,
  n = [],
  i,
}) => {
  const data = {
    datasets:
      //For loop to get all multiple- data for the chart
      (function(NursingObservations) {
        var out = [];
        var rows = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < NursingObservations.length; i++) {
          rows = rows + 100;
          out.push({
            label: "OxygenSaturation",
            pointStyle: o2sat,
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
            data: [{
              x: rows,
              y: NursingObservations[i].oxygensaturation,
              r: 5
            }]
          });
          out.push({
            label: "Temperature",
            pointStyle: temp,
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
            data: [{
              x: rows,
              y: NursingObservations[i].temperature,
              r: 5
            }]
          });
          out.push({
            label: "Pulse",
            pointStyle: heart,
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
            data: [{
              x: rows,
              y: NursingObservations[i].pulse,
              r: 5
            }]
          });
        }
        return out;
      })(NursingObservations)
  };
  return ( <
    div >
    //Bubble chart to display all the data 
    <
    Bubble data = {
      data
    }
    options = {
      options
    }
    width = "1000"
    height = "500" / >
    <
    /div>
  );
};
export default NursingObsComponent;
```

Click on the link second or any number of times same values should be retained in the chart, it should display all the values.

Instead only the latest data is displayed on the chart rest disappears.

Comment: Where is your onClick listener? which fetches the data? 
Can you create a sandbox and share that? It'll be easier to understand and debug

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shockley-cdiij?fontsize=14 - Please use this link.I have attached the files necessary. It is throwing some syntax error though while I did. Hope this will help you figure out the problem

Comment: couldn't get the code to work, please try and fix the sandbox, let me know when it works